# How to edit the default colors on Styled mode pie - Highscharts?

Tags: css, highcharts, highcharts-ng, dotnethighcharts

I tried editing the pie slice colors but it is filling in the label line also. How to avoid this issue?
`https://codepen.io/jenfloods/pen/WNRELrP`
Also, how to apply the stroke color outside? I've gone to the Highcharts documentation and it is not clear with This type of pie chart.
`https://www.highcharts.com/demo/styled-mode-pie` (default colors shown)

Comment: Hi @Jen Niles, What do you mean by `stroke color outside`?

Comment: Please provide more information about **what** you have tried already and where you are exactly stuck at. You cant expect people to do your work for free.

Comment: @ppotaczek If you look at the codepen example you can see the outside lines going to the text is filled it and it should be dashed line going to the text. Not sure what it is called to edit this to not fill?

Answer (score 0):

The connectors also have `highcharts-color-x` class and because of the fact that you redefine the color classes, they inherit styles from the other. As a solution add `fill: none` style for `highcharts-data-label-connector` class.

```
.highcharts-color-0 { fill: #e5ebed; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-1 { fill: #b2c3cb; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-2 { fill: #ccd7dc; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-3 { fill: #99afb9; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-4 { fill: #7f9ba8; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-5 { fill: #668797; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-6 { fill: #4c7385; stroke:#000000; }
.highcharts-color-7 { fill: #325f74; stroke:#000000; }

.highcharts-data-label-connector {
    fill: none;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ng62q9ej/

Comment: I apologize for a delayed THANK YOU @ppotaczek